# Application of Pigeon-Hole Principle to balls in bins.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, balls-in-bins

Given $n$ balls placed in $m$ boxes, prove that if $n < \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ then at least two boxes have same number of balls in them.

Comment: I've been able to roughly see through the above statement but I'm unable to formulate the proof formally in a mathematical manner.

Comment: I think you meant $>$.  Hint:  If you require that each box contain a unique number of balls then the best you can manage is $0$ in box #1, $1$ in box #2, and so on.

Comment: @lulu: $<$ makes sense given your hint.

Comment: @lulu I managed to observe that  $0+1+..(m-1) \geq \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$, but I couldn't convince myself that if the no. of balls in any bin is $\geq m$, then the at least two bins will have same no. of balls

Comment: @WillOrrick You are correct, of course.

Comment: @akshay: That's because it's false.  For example, for $m = 3$ and $n = 5$, you can have 0, 1, and 4 balls in your three bins.  The key is what happens when $n$ is _less_ than $\frac{1}{2} m (m-1)$.

Comment: @akshay  Note that the comment by WillOrrick is spot on, I confused myself as to the inequality.  You had it right.  Filling the boxes as ${0,1,2,3,...,m-1}$ is the most efficient possible way to put a different number of balls in each box.  It requires $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ balls to do it that way.  If you don't have that many balls you can't do this.

Comment: 4 answers, but the question has 0 up-votes, let's change that (+1) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier without the pigeonhole principle. Consider any arrangement of balls in $m$ boxes such that no two boxes have the same number of balls.  Then at most one box can be empty, requiring $0$ balls.  At most 1 additional box can have just one ball; the rest ($m-2$ boxes) have at least two balls.  At most 1 box can have 2 balls, and so on.  So the $m$ boxes must contain at least $0+1+2+\ldots + (m-1) = \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ balls.

Comment: I managed to observe that  $0+1+..(m-1) \geq \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$, but I couldn't convince myself that if the no. of balls in any bin is $\geq m$, then the at least two bins will have same no. of balls

Comment: The inequality in the question was "<". With $\ge$, you can't prove it any way.

Answer (score 2):

The **minimum** number of balls needed to fill *m* boxes with different number of balls is

$0 + 1 + 2 + 3 +.... + m-1 = \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$

since $n < \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$, at least 2 boxes must contain the same number of balls.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is equivalent to "if no two bins have the same number of balls, then $n\ge m(m-1)$."

Let $a_0$ be the number of bins with $0$ balls, $a_1$ the number with $1$ ball, and so on.  Then
$$
n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty ja_j.
$$
If no two bins have the same number of balls, then $a_j=0$ or $1$ for every $j$. In that case, exactly $m$ of the numbers $a_j$ equal $1$.  Use this to get the lower bound on $n$.

Alternatively, if one wants to apply the pigeonhole principle explicitly, one can do the following.  Label the balls with the numbers $1$ through $n$.  Label the bins with the numbers $1$ through $m$.  One is free to carry out the labeling of bins so that bin $2$ has at least as many balls as bin $1$, bin $3$ has at least as many balls as bin $2$, and so on.  Assume this has been done.  Let $b_j$ be the occupancy of bin $j$.  By assumption $b_1\le b_2\le\ldots\le b_m$.  Define $[1,k]$ to be the set $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.

Now there are $\binom{m}{2}=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ ways to choose two distinct bins.  If the occupancies $b_j$ are all distinct, the we can define the map $f:\{(i,j)\in[1,m]^2\mid j>i\}\rightarrow[1,n]$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
f((i,j))=&\text{the label of the $(b_i+1)^\text{st}$ ball in bin $j$, with the balls in bin $j$ ordered}\\ &\text{according to their labels,}
\end{aligned}
$$
and one can see that $f$ is one-to-one.  Now apply the pigeonhole principle with the pairs of distinct bins as the pigeons and the ball labels as the pigeonholes.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of $m$ distinct non-negative integers is $\geq 0 + 1 + 2 + \dots + (m-1)$.  One line of proof is to list the integers in increasing order.